# Delete content in text file

Tags: node.js

I've small form to get data from MongoDB and store in txt file. Then I want delete content in this file by click "Clear data". But I tried my code but it not working ? 
How can I fix that

**My JS file:**

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router(); 
var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
fs = require('fs');
/* GET home page. */ 
mongodb.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var test = db.collection('person');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
 res.render('index', {  
// my code to render index
 }); 
}); 

router.post('/', function (req, res) { 
// my code to create data.txt file 
});

});

router.post('/clear', function (req, res) {
  fs.writeFile('/path/to/file', '', function(){console.log('done')})
module.exports = router;
```

**My form:**

```
<form method="post"> 
    //my code
    <input type="submit" value=" OK " /> 
    <button type="submit"  formaction="/clear">Clear data</button>
    <p> Status :<%= status%></p> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 'fs', use the module '[fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra)'. This gives you all the features of 'fs' plus some extra functions. Your code would then become:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');  
.........

router.post('/clear',function (req,res){  
  fs.removeSync('path/to/file');
})
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Works like a charm always! :)